# PDFLibrary for Firemonkey C++Builder

Tags: c++, macos, pdf, printing, firemonkey

I need to print PDF documents from my C++ Fireminkey app. I have found a few libraries which will work for Windows platform. Have not found any library which can be used from Firemonkey to print on MAC OS. Any help?

Thanks, PP

Answer (score 0):

FastReport has a cross platform solution and claims PDF support: FastReport FMX

But I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Core Graphics pdf functions for displaying your PDF:
http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/osx-pdf-viewer/

This is for Delphi, but I think it should be pretty easy to convert to C++.